# Python - Convert JSON object data into a List

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have data in a **JSON** object with a `key:value` as shown below in **Python**. There are two records having same **ID** **13** for the **Hari** and **16** for the **Liz**.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import *
from operator import itemgetter

data = [
  {
    "fname": "Abc",
    "lname": "xyz",
    "id": 15,
    "club": "-",
    "date": "-"
  },
  {
    "fname": "Hari",
    "lname": "Lee",
    "id": 13,
    "club": "Manutd",
    "date": "2016-03-20T22:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "fname": "David",
    "lname": "James",
    "id": 14,
    "club": "Barca",
    "date": "-"
  },
  {
    "fname": "Hari",
    "lname": "Lee",
    "id": 13,
    "club": "Chelsea",
    "date": "2012-03-20T22:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "fname": "Liz",
    "lname": "Kiz",
    "id": 16,
    "club": "-",
    "date": "-"
  },
  {
    "fname": "Liz",
    "lname": "Kiz",
    "id": 16,
    "club": "Falkon",
    "date": "2014-03-20T22:00:00.000Z"
  }
]

newdata = []
#for item, value in enumerate(data):
  #for i,v in value.iteritems():
    #print value['id']
    #print value[i]
    #print i,v
    #newdata.append()
```

I want to reformat JSON data into list without a **key** and merge duplicated **ID** as a list of list. The record with same **ID's** will be mapped into list of list as shown below. How can I achieve this?

```
newdata = [[["Hari", "Lee", "Manutd", "2016-03-20T22:00:00.000Z"], ["Hari", "Lee", "Chelsea", "2012-03-20T22:00:00.000Z"]], 
    ["David", "James", "Barca", "-"], ["Abc", "xyz", "-" "-"], [["Liz", "Kiz", "-", "-"], ["Liz", "Kiz", "Falkon", "2014-03-20T22:00:00.000Z"]]]
```

Iterate over the new list data and write each list data as a row in excel (xlwt) file

```
for i1, v1 in enumerate(newdata):
  for i2,v2 in enumerate(v1):
    if(type(v2) is str):
      print v2
    else:
      for i3,v3 in enumerate(v2):
        print v3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the same ID you need to store data in a `dict`

```
ret_dict = {}
```

But `dict` isn't ordered. If you want to hold your order, you can you `OrderedDict`

```
from collections import OrderedDict
ret_dict = OrderedDict()
for element in data:
    # To remove 'id' from the dict 'element' use element.pop('id')
    # element.pop('id') return the value of id
    ret_dict.setdefault(element.pop('id'), []).append(element.values())
```

For me `ret_dict.values()` is already a good result:

```
>>> print ret_dict.values()
[[['xyz', '-', '-', 'Abc']], [['Lee', 'Manutd', '2016-03-20T22:00:00.000Z', 'Hari'], ['Lee', 'Chelsea', '2012-03-20T22:00:00.000Z', 'Hari']], [['James', 'Barca', '-', 'David']], [['Kiz', '-', '-', 'Liz'], ['Kiz', 'Falkon', '2014-03-20T22:00:00.000Z', 'Liz']]]
```

But for exactly what you want, you need to build a new list from the `values` of the last dict:

```
ret_list = [e[0] if len(e) == 1 else e for e in ret_dict.itervalues()]
```

*`itervalues()` to get the iterator of values instead of a list like `values()`*
Output:

```
>>> print ret_list
[['xyz', '-', '-', 'Abc'], [['Lee', 'Manutd', '2016-03-20T22:00:00.000Z', 'Hari'], ['Lee', 'Chelsea', '2012-03-20T22:00:00.000Z', 'Hari']], ['James', 'Barca', '-', 'David'], [['Kiz', '-', '-', 'Liz'], ['Kiz', 'Falkon', '2014-03-20T22:00:00.000Z', 'Liz']]]
```

Comment: You're a hero! Thanks!

Comment: How can I append element values in order and remove `id` value from list?

Comment: Normal `dict` isn't ordered. You must use `OrderedDict` to append element values in order. To remove **id** from a `dict` or `OrderedDict` you can use `pop`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I am in order as it was in JSON

Comment: Do you mind this order `{"fname": "Abc",
    "lname": "xyz",
    "id": 15,
    "club": "-",
    "date": "-"}`?

Comment: I would prefer list rather then `dict` as I don't need `keys` for my use case!

Comment: The problem is the dict `{"fname": "Abc", "lname": "xyz", "id": 15, "club": "-", "date": "-"}` doesn't have a order. You need to store your data in **OrderedDict** first.